# Restrict autocompletion with HLS and vscode

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-language-server

Autocompletion in the Haskell Language Server (with VScode) gives suggestions before a single character in the next word is typed (starts with `!!`) and adds often non-sense text. How can the useful auto-completion function be limited to start only after say 2 or 3 characers are typed?

I tried
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
in the settings, but it did not produce the desired effect.

Addition: could somebody start a Haskell-Language-Server tag?